# How to align resized items in RadToolBar when RadToolBar is resized?

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik

I am running into an issue with the radtoolbarbutton in a radtoolbar and can't find a solution anywhere.

My Radtoolbar looks like this...

```
    <div>
    <telerik:RadToolBar ID="rtlbCustomers" runat="server"
        Width="100%" Height="18px">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AddIco.png" Text="Add" Value="btnAdd" />
            <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/EditIco.png" Text="Change" Value="btnUpdate" />
            <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/DeleteIco.png" Text="Delete" Value="btnDelete" />
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadToolBar>
</div>
```

I have resized the items with this...

```
.RadToolBar .rtbItem {
        height:16px !important;
    }
```

Here is a picture of how it looks like..
[image: What my radtoolbar and items look like]

I am trying to get my buttons aligned properly in the radtoolbar so that the radtoolbarbuttons are in the grey area, but can't figure out how.
Has anyone ran into this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your dev toolbar to find the elements you need to change. Here is what seemed fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.RadToolBar .rtbOuter,
            div.RadToolBar .rtbIn,
            div.RadToolBar .rtbIcon
            {
                padding: 0;
                line-height: 14px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server" />
            <telerik:RadToolBar ID="rtlbCustomers" runat="server"
                Width="100%" Height="18px">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_16x16.png" Text="Add" Value="btnAdd" />
                    <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_16x16.png" Text="Change" Value="btnUpdate" />
                    <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_16x16.png" Text="Delete" Value="btnDelete" />
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadToolBar>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```